# Why the parent process of sudo -u remains in ps as root user? is it possible to avoid it? If not is it safe?

Tags: ubuntu, security

I'm trying to run my web browser as another user for security reasons with Ubuntu 20.04. The whole thing works but I notice that a process with "sudo -u browseruser" owned by root remains in process list.

This is how to replicate the behaviour (I use the same user instead of browseruser for the example to avoid details related to xhost authorization etc but you can understand what I mean):

```
marco@portatilinux:~$ sudo -u marco firefox &
marco@portatilinux:~$ exit
```

The browser window is still open as user marco...
On another terminal:

```
marco@portatilinux:~$ ps -aux |grep marco |grep root
root        5056  0.0  0.0  22880  4756 ?        S    13:34   0:00 sudo -u marco firefox
```

As you can see the process that start firefox remains active as root user until I close the browser windows. Probably this is the expected behaviour and it's ok but, to be sure, I have just a few questions:

Questions:

- Can this be a possible security hole for the whole system (if someone use a browser exploit it's easier for him to make a privilege excaletion to root or not if I run my browser in this way?)
- Is there any way to let this sudo -u process die but keep the browser process alive? (if I kill the process the browser window die with him)

I just ask because I don't want to create a worse possible security hole trying to do something better for my system.

I hope it's all clear.

Thanks

Marco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: `sudo` is setuid root, otherwise it wouldn't be able to do its job. So it always starts as root and there's nothing strange that it shows in process list as being owned by root. `sudo` drops privileges before spawning the child process, in your case `firefox`. So root privileges remain entirely within the parent process, that is actually only waiting for `firefox` to finish. I don't see a possibility to exploit it within the child process.

`sudo` has always worked this way and does extensive checks to avoid the possibility of root privileges being abused. Of course, you can never rule out the possibility of bugs in the software and the potential exploit, but this is highly unlikely. Given the popularity of `sudo`, the potential exploit probably would have been already found.

2: When you type `sudo -u marco firefox &`, you are actually running `sudo` in background, and `sudo` itself runs `firefox` **in foreground** (from its point of view) and waits for it to finish. You can get rid of the parent `sudo` process if you cause `firefox` to actually run in background - then the parent `sudo` process will immediately finish.

Instead of running `sudo -u marco firefox &` write a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec firefox &
```

Call the script for example `run_firefox` and place it in `/home/marco` directory. Then run: `sudo -u marco /home/marco/run_firefox` (without `&` at the end). If you check with `ps`, the `sudo` process won't be there.